# Regular expression filter angular2

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am working on an autocomplete functionality where regex has been used for filtering. The filter code currently is as below:

```
filterStates(val: string) {
    return val ? this.states.filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s.name))
               : this.states;
  }

}
```

Above `regex` worked fine for data structure like:

```
states=[{"name":"Alaska",code:1234},
{"name":"Bulgaria",code:12345},
{"name":"Colarado",code:12346},
{"name":"New Jersey",code:12347},
]
```

Heres the working plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/Pf2pWeUYo2mt7VzwCDs2?p=preview

But now there is a slight change in the data structure as shown in the `name` below:

```
 states=[{"name":"Alaska (AL)","code":1234},
{"name":"Bulgaria (BG)","code":12345},
{"name":"Colarado (CO)","code":12346},
{"name":"New Jersey (NJ)","code":12347},
]
```

I am not able to figure out as to how to generate the `regex` for `name`. I am a complete noob when it comes to regular expressions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This pattern isn't working. Its hindering the normal character search as well.

Comment: Is it necessary to use REGEX? as you can simply do it with custom Pipe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes just saw. Its not working.

Comment: @RonakBhatt There is no such restrictions as to whether to use regex or not. If something else can make it work, that answer would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Ok so https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html go to this link and check the example of `Flying-heroes pipe` And here is the plunkr for that example https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview

Comment: I have worked with pipes. But how do I make use of pipe in my situation?

Comment: Its not that hard try it you will get it I am sure

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to extract state name (no need to trim) : `^[\w ]+(?= \()`

Alaska (AL) => match **Alaska**

Bulgaria (BG) => match **Bulgaria**

New Jersey (NJ) => match **New Jersey**

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RQelma/2) on regex101

**Other possibility** which will match states when you type

Replace

```
return val ? this.states.filter(s => new RegExp(`^[\w ]+(?= \()`, 'gi').test(s.name))
          : this.states;
```

with

```
return val ? this.states.filter(s => (s && s.name && s.name.toLowerCase().substring(0, val.length) === val))
           : this.states;
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pf2pWeUYo2mt7VzwCDs2) is a plunker, try to type **a** then **l**

Comment: This matches the `name` exactly. But does't seem to work in plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/Pf2pWeUYo2mt7VzwCDs2?p=preview

Comment: I've added another way to achieve this (with a demo plunker)